# How to use AJAX File Browser for editing PDF files

Tags: webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

AJAX File Browser works great with Microsoft Office documents. However, I do note that the same does not work well with PDFs.

Currently in our application, 95% of the documents being reviewed/edited are PDFs. So is there a way I can make the PDFs work with Ajax File Browser?

Basically I'm looking at a solution/product which will help us with editing the PDFs using Adobe reader/professional and storing them directly on the server.

Comment: Any explanation of the downwote?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to open the the PDF document is using Java applet (or potentially other method with unrestricted access to local file system). The Ajax File Browser is provided with Java applet which mount mounts local file system and opens document for editing. The Java applet automatically engaged for non-MS Office documents or if MS Office is not found. This works on Windows, OS X and Linux.

You can find info about when the Java applet is engaged here: http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/opening_ms_office_docs